# d3 tree - Adjust horizontal distance between first level of parent and child nodes

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to set the horizontal distance for the first level of parent and child nodes?  At the moment, the distance betwenn those first level nodes to far, I would like to reduce this, but keep the distance between later levels the same as now.

```
// Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach( function ( d ) {
                d.y = d.depth * 250;
            } );

            nodes.forEach( function ( d ) {
                ( d.depth === 1 ) ? d.y = d.depth * 200: d.y = d.depth * 290;
            } );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfyge2rp/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fiddle, modify the code in **update** function:

```
// Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = (d.depth === 0 ? 50 : d.depth * 200);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please explain the parameters in the code that affect the tree distances between nodes?

Comment: In this case, y coordinate is the distance from the node to the left border of SVG. The depth of the root node is 0, so setting an especial case for depth === 0 gives distance between the root and the first level that differs from distance between subsequent levels (0 -> 1 : 150, 1 -> 2 : 200, 2 -> 3 : 200 and so on...)